# Multiple ViewComponents same Database Request

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I've got 3 ViewComponent's which are used to render main, side and footer navigation components for a given layout. However, they all access the same repository for very similar information. My DbContext is injected into the repository. The two alternatives would be to pass all the data in the ViewModel and then (a) pass the necessary object to the ViewComponent, or (b) take some time to convert the ViewComponent functionality into tag helpers.

What I am wondering is whether my current approach will result in instantiating the DbContext 3 times?

Comment: You might consider caching the data and use that in the three places

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have only one `DbContext` instance per request (of course only when you register it [as manual says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection)).